# How to save a Javascript Variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am working on a project that involves a global 'bank' of points.

I've been trying to use snippits of this code for it, but I can't get the variable to save after refresh.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript variable testing</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 500000;

    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

    };

    </script>
    <button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Click this bit</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">500000</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: localStorage['myKey'] = 'myValue' will persist after reload.

Comment: As @StepanYakovenko commented, use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 1):

Set you data to `localStorage`. Here is documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

That can get values after page refresh.

**Set you value using:**
`localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');`

**Get you value from local storage after page refreshed :**
`localStorage.getItem('key');`

Otherwise you can use `sessionStorage`, `Web SQL` & `cookies`.

***Example :***

```js
var clicks = 500000;

localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks); // set you value to localStorage

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks); // update you value
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

}

window.onload = function() {
  clicks = localStorage.getItem('clicks'); // get your value from localStorage
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Javascript variable testing</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click this bit</button>
  <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">500000</a>
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where in the code I should insert this?

Comment: @Billybobof Insert it into your external javascript file or inline `script` tag. Please read API Documentation that i provided. After you can get an idea.

Comment: That didn't really help. Please just copy-paste the code in my question, and add where it's supposed to go, then post it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to update the value when I click the button... :(

Comment: Which browser you're using?

Comment: Google Chrome. It's my default.

Comment: So inspect on your browser and goto Resources tab/Local Storage, see it's working

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't display it, which is what I want it to do.

Comment: Assuming your browser doesn't support localStorage or any other fault. Read the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Comment: But that code working for me!